# If atom ionization energy increases, how will the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) radiation temperature change today?

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

I know that the [Cosmic Microwave Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) (CMB) radiation is the leftover radiation of the photon emitted by the last cosmic-scale combination of electrons and ions to neutral atoms in the history of our universe.  Assuming that the atom ionization energy is higher, the initial radiation temperature will be higher, which tends to increase the CMB temperature today. However, the recombination and decoupling event will also happen earlier, such that the radiation will have to redshift more as it endures longer expansion of the universe, which tends to decrease the CMB temperature today. So will the CMB temperature eventually increase or decrease combining these two effects together? Or if there are other effects to be taken into account as well?

Comment: Are you keeping the density of ions and electrons the same as the density of protons and electrons?

Comment: @ProfRob I have no idea about this assumption. What if I assume all ions are hydrogen H+, i.e. protons, for simplicity?